# Got segfault accessing array of pointers to struct when using pointers instead of references

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

The function below takes a pointer to an array of pointers to `API_AddParType` structs and lists some of the fields of each array element. Everything works just like expected when accessing each element with `(*ppParams)[ii]`:

```
void ParamsListWrapper::ListParams2(API_AddParType** ppParams)
{
    unsigned long ii, nParams;
    nParams = BMGetHandleSize( (GSHandle)ppParams ) / sizeof(API_AddParType);

    // list params
    for ( ii = 0; ii < nParams; ii++ ) {
        WriteReport( "Param name = \"%s\", double = %f", (*ppParams)[ii].name, (*ppParams)[ii].value.real );
    }
}
```

Well, let's use some reference variable like `API_AddParType& param`:

```
void ParamsListWrapper::ListParams1(API_AddParType** ppParams)
{
    unsigned long ii, nParams;
    nParams = BMGetHandleSize( (GSHandle)ppParams ) / sizeof(API_AddParType);

    // list params
    for ( ii = 0; ii < nParams; ii++ ) {
        API_AddParType& param = (*ppParams)[ii];
        WriteReport( "Param name = \"%s\", double = %f", param.name, param.value.real );
    }
}
```

Now trying the same code with pointer to `API_AddParType`:

```
void ParamsListWrapper::ListParams3(API_AddParType** ppParams)
{
    unsigned long ii, nParams;
    nParams = BMGetHandleSize( (GSHandle)ppParams ) / sizeof(API_AddParType);

    // list params
    for ( ii = 0; ii < nParams; ii++ ) {
        API_AddParType* pParam = ppParams[ii];
        if (pParam != NULL) {
            WriteReport( "Param name = \"%s\", double = %f", pParam->name, pParam->value.real );
        } else {
            WriteReport( "Param is NULL" );
        }
    }
}
```

Got segmentation fault. How could it be? Why it fails when accessing data by pointers while references work without any problems?

Comment: Did you try to enable all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux) and to use http://valgrind.org/ and the `gdb` debugger?

Comment: Oops! I am using MSVC 2003 for this project.

Comment: You might consider http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function below takes a pointer to an array of pointers to `API_AddParType` structs

```
void ParamsListWrapper::ListParams2(API_AddParType** ppParams)
```

The function's argument is a pointer-to-pointer-to-`API_AddParType`, that could be a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to `API_AddParType`,

```
ppParams
   |
   v
pParam0|pParam1|pParam2|...
   |       |       |    ...
   v       v       v
  xyz     abc     mno   ...
```

or it could be a pointer to (a pointer to the first element of an array of `API_AddParType`),

```
ppParams
   |
   v
 pParams
   |
   v
param0|param1|param2|...
```

where I named the anonymous memory location `ppParams` points to `pParams` (pointer to params), and the reason the function receives a pointer to `pParams` instead of `pParams` itself is probably that the pointer `pParams` itself may be changed by the function.

Now, in the first case, `(*ppParams)[ii] = pParam0[ii] = the object ii units after the start of xyz`, so you never look at what `pParam1`, `pParam2` etc. point to (unless these pointers are set up to point inside the array whose first element `pParam1` points to).

In the second case, `(*ppParams)[ii] = pParams[ii] = the object ii units after the start of param0`, and you look at all the neatly arranged `paramN` in sequence. Looks good.

With

```
API_AddParType* pParam = ppParams[ii]
```

in the first situation, you'd look at `xyz`, `abc`, `mno`, ... in sequence, that looks good.

But in the second situation, `pParam` would become the pointer `ii` units after `pParams`, but that is not the first element of an array of pointers to `API_AddParType` of size larger than one, so accessing `ppParams[ii]` is undefined behaviour for `ii > 0`, and since it is unlikely that there happen to be valid pointers to `API_AddParType` just behind `pParams`, the access to `pParam->name` resp. `pParam->value.real` probably causes a segfault.

The fact that you got a segmentation fault with `ppParams[ii]`, but not with `(*ppParams)[ii]` strongly hints that the situation is actually the second, and not the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the second situation. Exactly as you proposed!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `API_AddParType* pParam = ppParams[ii];` to `API_AddParType* pParam = *ppParams;` and accessing `pParam->name` like this `pParam[ii].name`.

By accessing `(*ppParams)[ii]` you are manipulating a single `API_AddParType`, but accessing `pParam[ii]` you are manipulating an array of `API_AddParType`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line

```
API_AddParType* pParam = ppParams[ii];
```

to

```
API_AddParType* pParam = (*ppParams) + ii;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the last case, you're treating `ppParams` as an array of pointers, not as a pointer to an array.

The `ii`:th element of the array is `(*ppParams)[ii]` in the pointer case as well as in the other cases.
You're looking for its address, which is

```
API_AddParType* pParam = &(*ppParams)[ii];
```

or

```
API_AddParType* pParam = (*ppParams) + ii;
```